# A word for an object that contains two evolutionarily related objects

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, what should I call the animal that came before ape and human (each version of some object)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be looking for the word [progenitor](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/progenitor). This word is commonly used to describe a species that gave rise to another. For instance, "Australopithecus is the progenitor of modern hominid species."

Answer (score 7):

Biologists often speak of a "common ancestor" when referring to a species which no longer exists, but from which two or more other species have evolved.

tinyD makes a good point in the comments.  "Most recent common ancestor" would be the most precise term.

Comment: Although in practice it's likely to be the case, I'm not sure "common ancestor" need imply a species which no longer exists.

Comment: If you want to be more precise, [most recent common ancestor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_recent_common_ancestor) may be better, since plain 'common ancestor' covers a vast range of possible organisms.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, you might be talking about - *evolution branch*, more specifically and technically correct - you might be talking about *[biological classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_classification)* (see also taxonomic rank).

Specifically apes and humans are both in *superfamily* of *hominoidea* (see [changes of taxonomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ape#Changes_in_taxonomy)).

Comment: thx...This is what am exactly looking for ...but i need a generic name instead of hominoidea

Comment: What do you mean generic? In biological classification *hominoidea* is an instance of *superfamily* (however do note that this is very exact and technical meaning i.e. read the wikipedia article)

Answer (score 1):

> **a common ancestor**

works for a number of similar 'commonality' situations, when the similarities are derived from the same source.